# Execute user-defined query on list of dictionaries

Tags: python, sql

I have a set of data that a user needs to query using their own query string. The current solution creates a temporary in-memory sqlite database that the query is run against.

The dataset is a list of "flat" dictionaries, i.e. there is no nested data. The query string does not need to be SQL, but it should be simple to define using an existing query framework.

It needs to support ordering (ascending, descending, custom) and filtering.

The purpose of this question is to get a range of different solutions that might work for this use case.

```
import sqlite3

items = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'description': 'This is a description'},
    {'id': 3, 'comment': 'This is a comment'},
    {'id': 4, 'height': 1.78}
]

# Assemble temporary sqlite database
conn = sqlite3.connect(':memory:')
cur = conn.cursor()

knownTypes = { "id": "real", "height": "real", "comment": "text" }

allKeys = list(set().union(*(d.keys() for d in items)))
allTypes = list(knownTypes.get(k, "text") for k in allKeys)

createTable_query = "CREATE TABLE data ({});".format(", ".join(["{} {}".format(x[0], x[1]) for x in zip(allKeys, allTypes)]))
cur.execute(createTable_query)
conn.commit()

qs = ["?" for i in range(len(allKeys))]
insertRow_query = "INSERT INTO data VALUES ({});".format(", ".join(qs))

for p in items:
    vals = list([p.get(k, None) for k in allKeys])
    cur.execute(insertRow_query, vals)
conn.commit()

# modify user query here
theUserQuery = "SELECT * FROM data"

# Get data from query
data = [row for row in cur.execute(theUserQuery)]
```

Comment: What is your question? What doesn't work? If looking for variant solutions, try [CodeReview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the sugestion @Parfait, the above does work - but I hate reinventing the wheel. I guess I'm looking for something like `query(dataset, SQLqueryString)` that can safely translate user SQL into a list comprehsion.

Answer (score 0):

[YAQL](https://yaql.readthedocs.io/en/latest/getting_started.html#howto-use-yaql-in-python) is what I'm looking for.

It doesn't do SQL, but it does execute a query string - which is a simple way to do complex user-defined sorting and filtering.

Answer (score 0):

There's a library called [litebox](https://pypi.org/project/litebox/) that does what you want. It is backed by SQLite.

```
from litebox import LiteBox
 
items = [
    {'id': 1},
    {'id': 2, 'description': 'This is a description'},
    {'id': 3, 'comment': 'This is a comment'},
    {'id': 4, 'height': 1.78}
]

types = {"id": int, "height": float, "comment": str}

lb = LiteBox(items, types)
lb.find("height > 1.5")
```

Result: `[{'id': 4, 'height': 1.78}]`